# Single quote in in filter return exception querySelectorAll

Tags: 8, views

I face a problem when filter with single quote in field.
Anyone know why? And how to disable this exception?
[image: Single quote error]

Comment: On Drupal 8.5.1 I entered a single quote in the same "content" view & did not get any errors. Do you have any custom JS running?

Comment: Thanks 100pic. This is the original drupal source to reference, I only add Admin toolbar and no custom js, no theme, no custom function. I will run update to 8.5.1 to see any difference (it is 8.5.0)

Comment: The problem with single quote exists in 8.5.1 as well. What you uncovered is a possible security vulnerability with single quotes not being sanitized on a text input!

Comment: Weird I can't seem to recreate the problem. If you find the answer don't forget to post it here for future reference!

Comment: @100pic yes, the issue exists in 8.5.1 as Sensimple said. I found some patches can ignore the exception in console log and answer my question as your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this by using patch.
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2902769
Because this is a core funtion patch, I marked it as can-solve but not plan to use it myself, because the filter works still only some annoying console log.